Why my React Query does not instant update UI after delete? USING SUPABASE
Whenever delete is performed, supabase database is updated instantly but not in UI, If manually refreshed then updated list is shown to the UI... what to do please help!!
I have added EntryTable, inside it I am rendering EntryRow, that is where I am performing delete function through my react query
here useEntrys is fetching all the data from the database.
Entry Table
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useEntrys } from "../entry/useEntry";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";
import Empty from "./Empty";
import Menus from "./Menus";
import Table from "./Table";
import EntryRow from "../entry/EntryRow";
import AddEntry from "../entry/AddEntry";

const EntryTable = () => {
  const { isLoading, entrys } = useEntrys();

  if (isLoading) return <Spinner />;

  if (!entrys.length) return <Empty resourceName="Entrys" />;

  return (
    <div>
      <Menus>
        <Table>
          <Table.Header>
            <div>Employee ID</div>
            <div>Emp Name</div>
            <div>edit/Delete</div>
          </Table.Header>
          <div className="employeeSection">
            <Table.Body
              data={entrys}
              render={(entrys) => <EntryRow entry={entrys} key={entrys.id} />}
            ></Table.Body>
          </div>
          <div className="elem2">
            <AddEntry />
          </div>
        </Table>
      </Menus>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EntryTable;


Entry Row
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDeleteEntry } from "./useDeleteEntry";
import { useCreateEntry } from "./useCreateEntry";
import Table from "../ui/Table";
import Modal from "../Modal";
import Menus from "../ui/Menus";

import { FaEye, FaPencil, FaRegTrashCan } from "react-icons/fa6";
import CreateEntryForm from "./CreateEntryForm";
import ConfirmDelete from "../ui/ConfirmDelete";
import ShowEntry from "./ShowEntry";
import { supabase } from "../supabase";

const EntryRow = ({ entry, handleDelete }) => {
  const { isDeleting, deleteEntry } = useDeleteEntry();

  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);

  const { isCreating, createEntry } = useCreateEntry();

  const [empId, setEmpId] = useState(null);

  const { emp_id, emp_name } =
    entry;

  return (
    <div className="tableRow">
      <Table.Row>
        <strong className="employeeList">
         
          <p className="emp_id">{emp_id}</p>
          <p className="empName">{emp_name}</p>
        </strong>
      </Table.Row>
      <div className="menuContainer">
        <Modal>
          <Menus.Menu>
            <Menus.Toggle id={emp_id} />
            <Menus.List id={emp_id}>
              <Modal.Open opens="edit">
                <Menus.Button icon={<FaPencil />}>Edit</Menus.Button>
              </Modal.Open>

              <Modal.Open opens="show-details">
                <Menus.Button icon={<FaEye />}>Show Details</Menus.Button>
              </Modal.Open>

              <Modal.Open opens="delete">
                <Menus.Button icon={<FaRegTrashCan />}>Delete</Menus.Button>
              </Modal.Open>
            </Menus.List>

            <Modal.Window name="edit">
              <CreateEntryForm entryToEdit={entry} />
            </Modal.Window>

            <Modal.Window name="show-details">
              <ShowEntry entry={entry} />
            </Modal.Window>
          </Menus.Menu>

          <Modal.Window name="delete">
            <ConfirmDelete
              resourceName="entrys"
              disabled={isDeleting}
              onConfirm={() => deleteEntry(emp_id)}
            />
          </Modal.Window>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EntryRow;


API supabase
export const deleteEntry = async (id) => {
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("empManagement")
    .delete()
    .eq("emp_id", id)
    .select();

  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error("Employee entry slot couldn't be deleted");
  }

  return data;
};

Delete React Query
import { deleteEntry as deleteEntryAPI} from "../api/apiEntry";
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";

import toast from "react-hot-toast";

export const useDeleteEntry = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const { isLoading: isDeleting, mutate: deleteEntry } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: deleteEntryAPI,
    onSuccess: () => {
      toast.success("Entry deleted");
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: ["empManangement"],
      });
    },
    onError: (err) => toast.error(err.message),
  });
  return { isDeleting, deleteEntry };
};



If I need to pass any local state in order to update the UI, them let me know how should I pass...


I've only used Vue, so I don't know much about React, but I think the method is the same, so I'm leaving it here.
After searching, I found that "useRef" should be used to let me know that the value has changed.

Search for useRef and try to solve it ^^

To explain further, the entire data would have changed after deletion, but the changed data was not recognized, so there was no change. If you refresh, the data will change, right?
The reason is because it was newly viewed.
Therefore, after deletion, I need to inform the logic that the data value I have has changed so that the script can check the value and the data I have has changed. To do that, we use useRef.

I hope you solve this problem well ^^

yes exactly.. it would update in UI if I refresh. But how do I use useRef here

Looking at the coding source
I think this part of "entry" is the value of all searches, right?
If correct, on the "Entry Row" page
const allList = ref([]);
After doing
const allList = [...entry];
After storing it, display it on the screen as the data contained in allList and delete it!
In cases like vue/react, it is more efficient to copy the value and then use it rather than deleting/editing it using the original data

its not helping though buddy
